# Read list, create dictionary, and compare values in dictionary to an internal list in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to create a recipe generator where the user inputs ingredients that they have available, compares it to 'recipes' and suggests recipes to make.

I have a list of available ingredients stored in a list (created by user input) 'have_ingredients'

Right now, I have each 'recipe' in its own list, but this is really inefficient and requires basically creating code blocks for each recipe instead of using a loop. How can I do a similar iteration as below using the a recipe dictionary like recipes_dict??? Not sure how to do it, but I'd like to loop through dictionary values and if all values for a given key are available, append that key to a list of available recipes.

```
#ingredients user has
ingredients_have = ["Chicken", "Pesto", "Pasta", "Tomato", "Onion"]


hamburger = ["Ground Beef", "Tomato", "Onion", "Bread"]
surf_n_turf = ["Steak", "Fish"]
pesto_chicken = ["Chicken", "Pesto", "Pasta"]



recipes_dict = {"Hamburger": ("Ground Beef", "Tomato", "Onion", "Bread"), 
            "SurfnTurf": ("Steak", "Fish"), 
            "Pesto Chicken": ("Chicken", "Pesto", "Pasta")}


"""method using lists of recipes
if recipe requires an ingredient not available, append to needed_ingredients list
"""
needed_ingredients = []
avail_recipes = []
missing = 0 
for e in hamburger: ###looks through hamburger recipe (list)
    if e not in ingredients_have:
        missing =+1 
        needed_ingredients.append(e)   
if len(needed_ingredients) ==0:
    avail_recipes.append("hamburger")
else:
    print("To make a hamburger, you still need", *needed_ingredients)

#iterate the same as above for surf and turf, pesto chicken, etc.
    needed_ingredients = []
missing = 0 
for e in pesto_chicken:
    if e not in all_ingredients:
        missing =+1 #if ingredient is missing, add 1
        needed_ingredients.append(e)   
if len(needed_ingredients) ==0:
    avail_recipes.append("pesto chicken")
print("To make pesto chicken, you still need", *needed_ingredients)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
ingredients_have = ["Chicken", "Pesto", "Pasta", "Tomato", "Onion"]

recipes_dict = {"Hamburger": ["Ground Beef", "Tomato", "Onion", "Bread"], "SurfnTurf": ["Steak", "Fish"], "Pesto Chicken": ["Chicken", "Pesto", "Pasta"]}

available_recipes = []

for recipe, ingredients in recipes_dict.items():
  if all(ingredient in ingredients_have for ingredient in ingredients):
    available_recipes.append(recipe)
```

.items() allows you to retrieve keys and values from a dictionary. You can use a for loop with .items() to loop through every key, value pair in a dictionary. Then, for each key, value pair you can determine whether all of the values are in your ingredients_have list. There are multiple ways you can write this conditional but I used the all method.